# Surjectivity of polynomials

Tags: functions

Show that the mapping $f$:[$0,\infty$]$-R$ given $f(x)=x^2+2x-8$ for all $x$ belonging to [$0,\infty$) is invective but not surjective.

How do you prove the surjectivity part?

Because the general method is to suppose that $y$ is the codomain and then show that there exists an $x$ in the source so that $f(x)=y$. This usually involves solving the equation. However, it is not really applicable in the case when have to prove that for polynomials.

Comment: Do you mean "surjective"? :)

Comment: Yeah. Sorry for a typo. thank you :)

Comment: For the surjective part, it depends what you choose for codomain. Our polynomial is $ge -8$ for all $x\ge 0$. It takes on all values $\ge -8$.

Comment: I assume you meant *inJective*, since *inVective* refers to name-calling. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Note that $f(x)=x^2+2x-8=(x+1)^2-9\ge -9$.
So, it is injective since it is an increasing function on $(-1,\infty)$.
Take $y=-10$, then you will never have $f(x)=-10$ since $f(x)\ge -9$.

Answer (score 0):

The injectivity part is fairly easy because $f$ is increasing on the interval $[0, \infty)$.

For surjectivity, note that, since $f$ is increasing on the interval $[0, \infty)$, the minimum of $f$ on that interval must be $f(0) = -8$.

Answer (score 0):

The equation
$$x^2+2x-8=y$$
has no real solutions if
$$y<\min\{x^2+2x-8\}=\cdots$$

Answer (score 0):

The injectivity is easy: you have to check that for $x,y\in [0,\infty)$ with $x\neq y$ it holds $f(x)\neq f(y)$. This is true because the polynomial (a parabola), has its minimum at $x=-1$, hence it is monotone increasing in $[0,\infty)$.

The surjectivity is also easy: you should exhibit a point in the co-domain, actually the Whole $\mathbb{R}$, that is not coming from a point of the domain. In mathematics, if there exists $y\in\mathbb{R}$ s.t. there exists $x$ in the domain of $f$ s.t. $f(x)\neq y$. And this is true if you get any $y$ below the minimum of $f$, thus any real number strictly less than $f(-1)$. To be more precise, any point in the interval $[f(-1),f(0))$ is also sufficient.